# Do I need to cover freshly planted strawberries to protect against frost when it is snowing?

Tags: strawberries, frost, snow

I planted strawberries in a small raised bed this weekend, it is now snowing. Do I need to cover my strawberries to protect them from frost or will the snow provide that protection?

Comment: What variety of strawberry is it, and how cold will it get?

Comment: Not sure on the variety. Lows in the 20s highs in the 40s. USDA Zone 5b

Comment: Most strawberries should survive those temperatures, although as many are fit for the extreme end of that hardiness zone (which can get a lot colder than 20° F.) We'd probably be able to find out for sure if we knew the variety. If you got them locally, I imagine they'll survive your winters, snow or no snow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Snow is a good covering that protect against frost. Snow is made by snow flakes, so there is a lot of air (but also compact, so that such air cannot escape easily) , which insulate the soil.

On my region they say "Snow means bread, frost means hunger".

When there is no snow, you should care much more about frost. A garden tissue is good. Or just leaves (if frost is not extreme and long).